# Rest web service consumes XML with other parameters as well

Tags: resteasy

Would it be possible to consume an XML request along with other parameters as well?

These params are not Form Params.

The client would pass these params with XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when you talk about REST web service, you talk in terms of GET, POST, DELETE and PUT.

If you talk about the client only then POST and PUT will allow you to pass the user object, where as others will may ask for the id to perform the specific operation.

So, in a web service you have the parameter, ID, and it could be `pathparam/formparam/queryparam` and you have a @consume tag as well. But I have never seen a client that would pass these parameters with XML, because the URL path is not affected.